# Django: How to get objects instead of just foreign keys in annotate?

Tags: django

Annotate on a foreign key returns foreign keys. How can I get the objects themselves from the query?
In the following example 'the_user' is a foreign key in the "Vote" model:

```
Vote.objects.values('the_user').annotate(vote_count=Count('the_user')).order_by('-vote_count')
```

It would return

```
[{'the_user': 4, 'vote_count': 12} , {'the_user': 6, 'vote_count': 2}]
```

But I need the user objects themselves.. Not the ids

Answer (score 1):

`values()` does exactly that - returns values, use usual queryset

```
Vote.objects.annotate(vote_count=Count('the_user')).order_by('-vote_count')
```

Then each object in that queryset will have `vote_count` attribute.

Comment: I think that the_user might be a onetomany from the above description, considering that a vote_count is a aggregate Count on the number of users attached to a Vote?

Comment: I use values to count the results by 'the_user'. Otherwise the count won't work. From Django docs: "Instead of returning an annotated result for each result in the original QuerySet, the original results are grouped according to the unique combinations of the fields specified in the values() clause"

Comment: Perhaps if you also showed the model definition in your question it could help people understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should always query on the model which objects you want to get back in the resulted query set, so in your case:

```
qs = User.objects.annotate(vote_count=Count('vote')).order_by('-vote_count')
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting the foreign key and not the user objects is because of your use of values(), values returns a dict and not the model object. Use a select_related instead of values and that will resolve your problem.

Comment: If I'm understanding the OP correctly, he's looking to perform a GROUP BY query that returns the ForeignKey object, not just the id of the object.

Because he's wanting to perform the GROUP BY, using select_related() instead of values will not perform the query as expected.